# Restrict who can see facebook login button for Beta

Tags: facebook, authentication, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm doing a private beta and the only login method is through facebook.

The problem is that anyone with a facebook account who can see the facebook login button can login. If you have standard e-mail authentication then you can use a `token` to access the sign up page and then login regularly going forward (any users who try to login will just get denied). However, with facebook login we don't know if they've registered yet. I do have cookies but if they login from different devices then we still find ourselves in this same predicament.

I'd like

1. users with access to be able to sign in easily
2. users without access should not be able to sign in

Possible solutions:

1. have users enter their e-mail address or code to then expose the facebook button (if a code is in the url then you can make the api call without user input, or you can make an api call after a user enters in their e-mail)
2. always follow the same link to login (with a code attached)

Is there a preferred method of solving this problem? Anything that I'm missing?

Comment: Can you make the login function only accessible on a certain page? Like http://somesite.com/beta ?

Comment: @PaulOliver you could but that just makes it tougher to login for existing users (not easy to remember that specific url)

Comment: Is your site visited so often by people that they'd log in frequently with Facebook? Can't you whitelist a few users in a database and if they aren't in that list, prevent access to the application?